# Auto-open a pinned file in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Context: I have a todo list file I always want to open as a pinned file in VSCode, but it's a pain having to reopen it manually for each project.

Is there any way to force VSCode to always open a particular file any time I open a new VSCode window?

Edit:
this should ideally work for *all* folders, as I often access remote folders over SSH that will not have workspaces created for them

Comment: you could create a workspace: `file>add folder to workspace` and then `file>save workspace`

Comment: my VSC remembers the files I had open the last time I opened the folder

Comment: @AlessandroCandeloro In my case I would like to customize dev-container to open a jupyter notebook automatically after the workspace is started. How do I do that?